# Django RegexField Letters and Numbers only

Tags: python, regex, django

I need a regexfield in a django form to only accept letters and numbers, and nothing else.  I've tried this, but it didn't work:

```
myfield = forms.RegexField(label=("My Label"), max_length=31, regex=r'[a-zA-Z0-9]',
        error_message = ("This value must contain only letters and numbers."),
```

I am not very good at using regular expressions.  Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 7):

regex=r'[a-zA-Z0-9]',

Is one letter.

Do you want more than one letter?  Then use a repeat

regex=r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+',

There are numerous tutorials on regular expressions.  Please google for "Regular Expression Tutorial."

Comment: I did google for it, hence the solution I came up with.  It clearly wasn't correct though.  Using your solution: regex=r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+', I can still use use underscores, any idea why?

Comment: Because.  Your pattern does not specify the WHOLE string.  You need `^` and `$`.  "I did google for it".  Keep trying, then.  There are **good** tutorials that will help you.

Comment: Then your answer is not correct either, just noting... no need for the rudeness either.

Answer (score 5):

```
regex=r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$',
```

this will only accept letters and numbers and will require at least one symbol

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Can yoube more specific?

An "error" I can spot right away is that it will only accept a single charactter. You're missing a repetition in the `regex` argument. Try adding a `*` or `+` at the end (see python's `re` module documentation for details.

Comment: It didn't work means that the form does not validate correctly.  As in I enter "asdasdf" and it still throws a validation error.

Comment: I figured it out.  I needed the carrot and dollar sign at the end: regex=r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$',

Comment: @bababa: It's caret, not carrot :)